# Get fan count for lots of facebook pages

Tags: php, facebook, api

I have lots of facebook pages (we're a club) and would like to display them in order of their fan count. I'm new to php and know nothing about API. All the code I can find to return the fan count refers to apps, and needs their IDs and secrets, which I don't have with a business page.

I have this:

http://api.facebook.com/method/fql.query?format=json&query=select+fan_count+from+page+where+page_id%3D355692061120689

When I put this into a browser it gives me what I need. How do I write this in php so it gives me a variable to work with?

Thanks.

Comment: OK I have just found this which is helpful

 http://graph.facebook.com/355692061120689

I still don't know how I get this information into my php? Please don't vote this question down :( I just need a nudge in right direction as I only started php monday! Even a link to something I can research would help please

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This data is called a JSON string.  There is a function in php called `json_decode()`.  Using this in tandem with `file_get_contents()`, we can retrieve the value, and echo it in php:

```php
<?php
$json = file_get_contents('http://api.facebook.com/method/fql.query?format=json&query=select+fan_count+from+page+where+page_id%3D355692061120689');

$decode = json_decode($json);

echo $decode[0]->fan_count;
?>
```

To be clear, `$decode` is an array, whose first value is a php object, whose variable fan_count holds the data.

In regards to the graph url, just change..

```php
echo $decode[0]->fan_count;
```

to..

```php
echo $decode->likes;
```

of course assuming you've changed the `file_get_contents()` url to that of your graph url.

Comment: lol - wish I'd seen your update earlier - figured I had to change to the new 'likes' and not fan-count. Got it working using explode() twice :D

Will change to this now.

Learnt so much this morning - you're a star!

Comment: I apologize for not alerting you, heh.